# Hibarnate org.hibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type SimpleStringProperty

Tags: java, database, hibernate, javafx

This question has been asked many times but none of the answers seems to help me at all so i'll try asking it again and hope for luck:

I have the class **Score**

```
    @Entity(name="SokoTable")
    public class Score implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private private SimpleIntegerProperty id;

    @Column(name="Username")
    private SimpleStringProperty userName;
    @Column(name="Level")
    private SimpleStringProperty levelName;
    @Column(name="Steps")
    private SimpleIntegerProperty steps;
    @Column(name="Time")
    private SimpleIntegerProperty time;
    public Score(){ 
    }
    public Score(String userName, String levelName, int steps, int time) {
        super();
        this.userName = new SimpleStringProperty(userName);
        this.levelName = new SimpleStringProperty(levelName);
        this.steps = new SimpleIntegerProperty(steps);
        this.time = new SimpleIntegerProperty(time);
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName.get();
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName.set(userName);
    }
    public String getLevelName() {
        return levelName.get();
    }
    public void setLevelName(String levelName) {
        this.levelName.set(levelName);
    }
    public int getSteps() {
        return steps.get();
    }
    public void setSteps(int steps) {
        this.steps.set(steps);
    }
    public int getTime() {
        return time.get();
    }
    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time.set(time);
    }   
    }
```

The class **SokoDBManager** which will manage the Database

```
public class SokoDBManager {

    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static SokoDBManager instance=new SokoDBManager() ;
    public static SokoDBManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private SokoDBManager() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }

    private static void searchScoresWhoseNameStartsWith(String prefix) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from SokoTable where Username LIKE :prefix");
        query.setParameter("prefix", prefix + "%");

        List<Score> list = query.list();
        for (Score e : list) {
            System.out.println(e.getUserName());
        }
        session.close();
    }


    public void addScore(Score score){
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            session = factory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(score);
            tx.commit();            
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (session != null)
                session.close();
        }       

    }
    // Method to print all Scores
    public static ObservableList<Score> getScoreList(String Levelname) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        ObservableList<Score> list=null;

        try {       
            Query query = session.createQuery("from SokoDB.Score where Level =:Levelname Order by Steps");      
            query.setParameter("Levelname",Levelname);      
            list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(query.list());
            System.out.println(list.getClass());
            for (Score e : list) {
                System.out.println(e.getUserName());
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { 
            session.close();            
        }
        return list;

    }


    public void close() {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

for example if i'll try to run this code:

```
ObservableList<Score> data=SokoDBManager.getScoreList("Level 1");
        for(Score e :data)
            System.out.println(e.getTime());
```

I'll get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at view.SokobanViewer.openFile(SokobanViewer.java:64)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty, at table: SokoTable, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(Level)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at SokoDB.SokoDBManager.<init>(SokoDBManager.java:29)
    at SokoDB.SokoDBManager.<clinit>(SokoDBManager.java:21)
    ... 54 more
```

Is it related to the SimpleStringProperty? 
what could be the reason for this error and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Probably you need some kind of converter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Hibernate to "see" the properties as having the underlying types `String` and `int`, not the types used for implementing observability by JavaFX (`StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty`).

If you place the `Column` annotation on the fields, Hibernate will use an `AccessType` of `FIELD`, i.e. it will match the type based on the type of the field. To use an `AccessType` of `PROPERTY`, in which Hibernate looks at the `get/set` methods, not the fields, annotate the `get` methods instead. You can also explicitly specify the access type with the `Access` annotation.

Also, as an aside, note that you have a bug in the implementation of your entity. If you call the default constructor, and then a `set` method (which is *exactly* what Hibernate will do), you get a null pointer exception as you never instantiate the property instances. It's best to make these final and instantiate them inline.

```
@Entity(name="SokoTable")

// the next line is optional if you annotate the get methods (as done below):
@Access("AccessType.PROPERTY")

public class Score implements Serializable{

    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ; 

    private final StringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
    private final StringProperty levelName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
    private final IntegerProperty steps = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;
    private final IntegerProperty time = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

    public Score(){ 
    }
    public Score(String userName, String levelName, int steps, int time) {
        super();
        setUserName(userName);
        setLevelName(levelName);
        setSteps(steps);
        setTime(time);
    }

    @Column(name="ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    @Column(name="Username")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName.get();
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName.set(userName);
    }
    @Column(name="Level")
    public String getLevelName() {
        return levelName.get();
    }
    public void setLevelName(String levelName) {
        this.levelName.set(levelName);
    }
    @Column(name="Steps")
    public int getSteps() {
        return steps.get();
    }
    public void setSteps(int steps) {
        this.steps.set(steps);
    }
    @Column(name="Time")
    public int getTime() {
        return time.get();
    }
    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time.set(time);
    }   
}
```

Have a look at [this blog post](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html) for more details.